# Select2 Matcher not working Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror, jquery-select2, matcher

For some reason I cannot get matcher to work in my currency converting app. I keep getting:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

```
function matchCustom(params, data) {


  // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
  if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
    return data;
  }

  // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
  if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
    return null;
  }

  // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
  // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
  if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    return data;
  }

  // custom search using lookup data
  if ($(data.element).data('lookup').toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    return data;
  }



  // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
  return null;
}



$(".js-example-templating").select2({
    templateSelection: formatState,
    templateResult: formatState,
    matcher: matchCustom

});
```

```
<select class="js-example-templating"   >
            <option value="GBP"  selected>GBP</option>
            <option value="EUR" data-lookup="Spain, Italy" >EUR</option>
</select>
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this error is because you have not defined data-lookup for the first option but you are trying to reference it in your code.

```
<option value="GBP"  selected>GBP</option>
```

You are trying to reference it here

```
// custom search using lookup data
  if ($(data.element).data('lookup').toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    return data;
  }
```

You need to make sure that `lookup` property exists to avoid this error. You need to change your if condition like below

```
if ( typeof $(data.element).data('lookup') !== 'undefined' && $(data.element).data('lookup').toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
```

You can check the demo at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q3Lkhpg/)

Comment: Ooh finally I can see it, I just noticed that tag and the rest of the currencies I get from the API didn't have the look-up tags. I will add this to them. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The first option tag do not contain a data-lookup attribut in your example, maybe this is why you got the error !